# Input string never equals the random string

Tags: c#, asp.net

It should return "success", but it always returns the answer of "fail".

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Random rnd = new Random();
  randomNumber = (rnd.Next(100000, 999999)).ToString();
  Label1.Text = randomNumber;
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (TextBox1.Text != randomNumber)
  {
    Label1.Text = "fail";
  }
  else
  {
    Label1.Text = "success";
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML part.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code? For example, how is randomNumber declared? Show us some of the HTML too, where Label1 and TextBox1 are.

Comment: Sir, I already put it below.

Comment: And value you submit in text box is equal to random number?

Comment: The range of the random numbers is huge (899999 different random numbers). The probability that you enter the right number is very small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `randomNumber` is a class-level field. Its value will **not** be persisted between requests.

If you want to persist the value between requests, then you need to store it in the `ViewState`:

```
private string RandomValue
{
    get { return (string)ViewState["RandomValue"]; }
    set { ViewState["RandomValue"] = value; }
}

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    RandomNumber = (rnd.Next(100000, 999999)).ToString();
    Label1.Text = RandomNumber;
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text != RandomNumber)
    {
        Label1.Text = "fail";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "success";
    }
}
```

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100))

Comment: Sir, I have put the String under the Public part.
But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Read my answer again. Making a field `public` won't change the fact that it **will not be persisted between requests**. Store the value in the `ViewState`.